# Can't shadow python time module with my own time module

Tags: python, datetime, time, import, python-3.6

I have a folder with three files:

- test.py
- time.py
- datetime.py

time.py and datetime.py are identical:

```
def ticks_ms():
    return 5
```

When test.py looks like this:

```
import datetime as t
print(t.ticks_ms())
```

it prints 5. If I change it to:

```
import time as t
print(t.ticks_ms())
```

I get:

```
AttributeError: module 'time' has no attribute 'ticks_ms'
```

Why can I shadow the datetime module but not the time module?

Comment: It seems like a terrible idea to purposely overshadow built-in modules. Why would you want to do that?

Comment: I don't know about the "why", but here is a "how": name your module "my_time.py", and import it this way: `import my_time as time`.

Comment: Why I want to do this:
I'm working on a project using micropython. The version of the time module that is available on the microprocessor has the ticks_ms() function, returning the number of milliseconds since the processor started. When developing the code I'm writing on my computer, and in order to easily test the code without having to upload it to the microprocessor I have made "simulating" modules for all the onboard stuff. The normal time module don't have the ticks_ms() function, an I can't just name it something else because then the import don't work on the microprocessor.

Comment: I'm quite certain there are lots of other better ways to accomplish what I'm trying to do, and I will investigate that now.
The reason for asking the question here was that I discovered the (to me at least) rather strange difference between the time and datetime modules. Thanks to Jims great answer I now see why that is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why can I shadow the `datetime` module but not the `time` module?

Because Python will first search for built-in modules (implemented in C) before searching for normal `.py` files (in various locations, starting from your `cwd`, see the contents of `sys.path`).

You can see this by inspecting `sys.meta_path` which contains finders that are queried when an import for a module occurs (a module which hasn't been found in `sys.modules`):

```
>>> sys.meta_path
[<class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>, 
 <class '_frozen_importlib.FrozenImporter'>, 
 <class '_frozen_importlib_external.PathFinder'>]
```

First in this list is `BuiltinImporter` which, as it's name implies, handles the finding of built-in modules.

The time module is built-in (see `sys.builtin_module_names` for a list of these):

```
>>> time
<module 'time' (built-in)>
```

and is found before a search for your `time.py` is performed. While `datetime.py` isn't:

```
>>> datetime
<module 'datetime' from '/home/jim/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/datetime.py'>
```

and so the `datetime.py` in your current working dir masks it (`PathFinder` finds `datetime.py` by looking at the entries listed in `sys.path`).

---

Yes, you can re-order the finders in `sys.meta_path` and put the `PathFinder` first thereby resulting in `time.py` getting found but, please don't do that (unless you're just experimenting :-).